# How to get transaction history in hyperledger

Tags: transactions, hyperledger, history

I am currently developing programs using hyperledger. I want to get each tx (transaction) data from hyperledger like this.

```
A changed value "On"
A changed value "Off"
B changed value "On"
...
```

However, there seems to be no api that get the transaction history. This question is similar to the [40466580](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40466580/how-to-get-all-transaction-history-against-a-chaincode-in-hyperledger-fabric) question. Is it best to just fix the program in chaincode? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question with a link to 40466580.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use following method of Hyperledger shim interface to get history of a particular key:-

> GetHistoryForKey(key string) (HistoryQueryIteratorInterface, error)

For more details, please check hyperledger shim interface documentation:-

[Hyperledger Shim Interface](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L233)

For usage, please check following link:-

[GetHistoryForKey() usage](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/-/blob/core/chaincode/shim/chaincode.go#L702:28&tab=references)