# User transaction history hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am building a hyperledger fabric blockchain application where several users interact. It seems to be working. Using hyperledger explorer I can also view the blocks and transactions in the blockchain.

However, it is not clear to me how to see get the transaction history for 1 user (based on his / her identity key)?

Basically, like for a customer of a bank, I would like to get only the transactions relevant to a particular user to provide him/her with a transaction overview.

Is there a tool for this? Is it integrated into Fabric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several different ways to go about this.

1. **On-chain**: You'd write a chaincode function to return the corresponding transactions. To do this you need to keep track of each user's submitted transactions by storing the transaction UUIDs in the chaincode state (`stub.PutState`). With `stub.getState` you can later retrieve the state and return the transaction list. (inspired by [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40476351/5726546))
2. **Peer SDK**: As far as chaincode-independent transaction history goes I'm not aware of any API calls that support this. You can only get a transaction by its UUID.
3. **Off-chain**: Since you're already using Hyperledger Explorer, you should have a [Postgres database](https://blockchain-explorer.readthedocs.io/en/master/architecture/databaselayer.html) containing indexed transaction data. You can query the transactions table from your application by filtering for the `creator_id_bytes`. Since Hyperledger Explorer needs to fetch new transactions from the peer first, there is some additional latency with this approach compared to 1/2.